# Why does putting a variable in angle brackets access the first value of an array

Tags: javascript

I've been using this trick a few time now but I still can't wrap my head around why this works and can't seem to find the answer. Could anybody please explain ?

```js
let myArray = [0, 1]
let [myVar] = myArray
console.log(myVar) // outputs 0
```

How is [myVar] the same thing as putting [0] behind myrArray ?

Edit: already asked and answered here :
[Multiple assignment in javascript? What does [a,b,c] = [1, 2, 3]; mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986348/multiple-assignment-in-javascript-what-does-a-b-c-1-2-3-mean)

Thank you everyone

Comment: It is destructuring the array and get the first index element and put it into `myVar`. [Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: See the ["Array destructuring" section here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68649003)

Comment: For some reason my brain had not connected Array destructuring to this... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) reference.

But basically, the brackets can be used to assign individual elements of a structure/array to variables, and it can be used with more than one, as well.

E.g.:

```js
let myArray = [0, 1]
let [myVar1, myVar2] = myArray
console.log(myVar1) // outputs 0
console.log(myVar2) // outputs 1
```

PS: fyi these `[]` are square brackets, and these `<>` are angle brackets.

Comment: This might be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

it is  call "Destructuring_assignment"
you can read more on that here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment